# convert input then compare it and display result in new form

Tags: php

```
 _________________________________________________________
|What i must | the value format stored | the result must |
|   type     |      in data base       |   be shown      |
 _________________________________________________________

|  8.30     |            8.5           |     8.30        |
|_________________________________________________________
```

I'm using a php search page and I want to convert result from sexagesimal(8.30, as I enter) to decimal (8.5), in order to compare it with values in database and then display them as sexagesimal (8.30, as i entered in first time) and not as decimal (8.5, which is the value saved in my data base).
So if there is a direct query that I can use to fetch my search.
btw I can't change type of my database field to TIME because I saved it as VARCHAR to compare between values, because I'm trying to build an attendance system

Comment: *"can't change type of my data base field to TIME because i saved it at VARCHAR to compare between values"* - wut? That makes no sense. Store it as `TIME`, that's what that column type is for!

Comment: right i try to use that query that already i use it before but didn't work (PHP /MySQL Select data from table and display result in different form) so i asked my question again and no one answer me

Comment: i just want to ask if i can convert 8.30 to 8.5 then back 8.30 it is exactly what i want and if there is no way then i must use another method (i just asked if that possible or not since am joiner in programing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Converting sexagesimal to decimal

```
<?php
$sexagesimal = 8.30;
$hour = explode(".",$sexagesimal);
$minutes = $sexagesimal - $hour[0];
$decimalminutes = ($minutes/60)*100;
$decimal = $hour[0] + $decimalminutes;
echo $decimal;
?>
```

### Converting sexagesimal to decimal

```
<?php
$decimal = 8.5;
$hour = explode(".",$decimal);
$minutes = $decimal - $hour[0];
$sexagesimalminutes = ($minutes/100)*60;
$sexagesimal = $hour[0] + $sexagesimalminutes;
echo $sexagesimal;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Converting sexagesimal to decimal**

```
function convertToDecimal($sexagesimalTime)
{
    if (!empty($sexagesimalTime)) {
        $hms = explode(":", $sexagesimalTime);
        $hours = $hms[0];
        $minutes = $hms[1];
        $decimalTime = $hours + round($minutes / 60, 2);
        return $decimalTime;
    } else {
        $decimalTime = '';
    }
    return $decimalTime;
}
```